# Tkinter.Text index expressions and unicode

Tags: python, unicode, tkinter

Let us consider the following code:

```
from tkinter import Tk, Text

root = Tk()

text = Text(root)

text.insert("end", "abcdefgh\nабвгґдеє\n一伊依医咿噫欹泆")

print(text.index("1.4+1l"), text.index("1.4+2l"))
print(text.index("3.4-1l"), text.index("3.4-2l"))
```

Some people (for example me) would expect it to print `2.4 3.4` and `2.4 1.4`, because `+1l` and `-1l` are supposed to preserve the column if the line is long enough. Instead, it prints `2.2 3.2` and `2.6 1.8`. It looks like it depends on the number of bytes needed to encode each character.

Should it be this way? Is it documented somewhere? Should I just use something like

```
line, column = old_index.split(".")
new_index = text.index(f"{line+1}.{column}")
```

instead of `+1l` if I care about columns being preserved?

Comment: I can duplicate your results, but I can't explain them. It appears to be a bug in the underlying tk library.

Comment: @bryan-oakley indeed, I can reproduce it in pure Tk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems to be Tk-related, not Python-related:

```tcl
package require Tk 8.6

pack [text .t]
.t insert end "abcdefgh\nабвгґдеє\n一伊依医咿噫欹泆"

puts "[.t index 1.4+1l] [.t index 1.4+2l]"
puts "[.t index 3.4-1l] [.t index 3.4-2l]"

exit 0
```

Output:

```
2.2 3.2
2.6 1.8
```

So I asked a [second question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44078060/tk-text-widget-index-expressions-and-unicode).