# Tk text widget index expressions and Unicode

Tags: unicode, tcl, tk-toolkit

(this question is based on [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44059438/tkinter-text-index-expressions-and-unicode/))

Let us consider the following code:

```tcl
package require Tk 8.6

pack [text .t]
.t insert end "abcdefgh\nабвгґдеє\n一伊依医咿噫欹泆"

puts "[.t index 1.4+1l] [.t index 1.4+2l]"
puts "[.t index 3.4-1l] [.t index 3.4-2l]"

exit 0
```

Output:

```
2.2 3.2
2.6 1.8
```

I would rather expect `+1l` and `-1l` to preserve the column if the line is long enough, that is, to print `2.4 3.4` and `2.4 1.4`. It looks like the result depends on the number of bytes needed to encode each character.

Should it be this way? Is it documented somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

What font are you using? What exact patch-version of Tk are you using? (It should be reported by doing `puts [package require Tk]`.)

I think the text widget currently uses character widths when working out the actual motions when doing index movement by lines. *This has changed between past versions*. The problem is that different bits of code want different things: sometimes you want visible motions (e.g., when handling users' cursor motion, *especially* with tabs set) and sometimes you want character-space motions (which is what you appear to be expecting).

Tk shouldn't ever be doing anything (you can see) with the byte widths of unicode characters. It's really supposed to handle that transparently (at least for any character in the Basic Multilingual Plane; you might find bugs outside that).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The version is 8.6.5. About the font: `puts [.t cget -font]` tells me the font is `TkFixedFont`, but if I change the font (for example, to `FreeMono` or `FreeSerif`) then the numbers don't change, although the appearance of the text changes significantly. Also, if I visualize the `+1l` cursor movement through a large multilingual text, it isn't smooth at all, it jumps wildly hither and thither. But if the text is, for example, Cyrillic only or Latin only, the movement is smooth. At least this is the behavior on my computer.

Comment: Changing the font _would_ change the look; that's the main reason why people change fonts. It sounds like some sort of failure case, but it might be due to something unexpected (surrogates?) so it'll take deeper investigation to figure out what's wrong. There's some [current work](http://core.tcl.tk/tk/timeline?r=revised_text) to improve the text widget — again — so it's definitely worthwhile [opening an issue](http://core.tcl.tk/tk/tktnew).

Comment: Also, in at least some “monospace” fonts (i.e., the default one in the terminal on my machine) those Chinese characters are wider than the Latin and Cyrillic characters.

Comment: it is true, but it doesn't explain the behaviour. Cyrillic `а`, for example, is not visibly wider or thinner than Latin `a` in the fonts I've used, but the behavior persists even if you use `aaaaaaaa` and `аааааааа` instead of `abcdefgh` and `абвгґдеє`.